# C++: how to reuse my template code

Tags: c++, templates, machine-learning, function-pointers, random-forest

I am writing a few algorithms to build random forests, each forest will be
trained on separate data with separate functions (each tree will use a set of
functions with a fixed signature however different trees will be trained using
different sets of functions which could have a different signature), however I
would like to just write the code to build the random trees once, using
templates. I currently have something like the following:

template class T corresponds to the training data type (i.e. image patch, or
pixel) template class V corresponds to the function pointer type

```
template<class T, class V>
class RandomTree{

    void build(RandomTreeNode<T>& current_node,
               vector<V>& functions,
               vector<T>& data) {
        ... some code that basically calls a function passing in data T
    }
}
```

and I create the object like so:

```
typedef double (*function_ptr)(TrainingDataPoint& data_point);

RandomTree<TrainingDataPoint, function_ptr> tree = ...
```

The problem is that, for efficiency reasons, for one of the trees I'm
building, I want the set of functions (function_ptr's) to take in not only the
TrainingDataPoint(template type T) but a cache of data. So that my function
pointer will look like:

```
typedef double (*function_ptr)(TrainingDataPoint&,
                               unordered_map<string, cv::Mat>& preloaded_images);
```

Now the problem is, I cant think of a way to keep the RandomTree class generic
but have some function sets (template type V) that take more than just the
training point (template type T).

So far I have thought of:

1. Making the cache global so that the functions can access it
2. adding a pointer to the cache to each training data point (but who is responsible for the clean up?)
3. Adding a third template parameter to the RandomTree, but in this case if I am building a tree that doesn't require this third parameter, what do I put there?

None of these options seem particularly appealing to me, hopefully someone can lend some experience and tell me of a better way?

Thanks

Comment: What is type `cv`?  Is it a fixed type?

Comment: Sorry should be cv::Mat (have edited) it's a Matrix class from the openCV lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a functor for the functions that need state.  A functor in C++ is a class (or struct) with an overloaded operator(), so that an instance of the functor can be "called like" a function.  The arguments to the functor in the RandomTree should be exactly those parameters that vary and are under the control of the RandomTree, the rest should be bound outside.  A sample functor with additional state that wraps a function:

```
template<typename Retval, typename Arg1, typename ExtraData>
struct BindExtraData
{
  typedef Retval(*func_type)(Arg1, ExtraData);
  BindExtraData( ExtraData const& d_, func_type func_ ):d(d_), func(func_) {};
  ExtraData d;
  func_type func;
  Retval operator()( Arg1 a1 )
  {
    return func(a1, d);
  }
};
```

but you can do better.  If this is a one-off, there is no need to make it a template.  bind2nd(well, binder2nd) is the standard library version of the above, and will be better written.

Comment: In C++11, `bind1st` and the like are deprecated for `std::bind`.

Comment: I want to use the same ExtraData object accross all BindExtraData types, so would the member d be of type ExtraData *d and in the constructor I would assign as d = *d_. How do I handle cleanup of this object?

Comment: I would just punt and use std::shared_ptr<ExtraData> if I needed to share a pointer over a bunch of objects whose lifetime I don't have strong control over.  Alternatively, if you know that the functor is only going to be used within the a particular call to RandomTree, or over the lifetime of your particular RandomTree instance, you could use a ExtraData* d pointing at an instance of ExtraData with a longer lifetime than the functors are going to have.  A std::shared_ptr is much easier to reason about, however.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another paramter to RandomTree that takes in a Cache. The default would be an empty cache if not provided. For example

```
template<typename T, typename V, typename CacheDataType = EmptyCache>
class RandomTree{ ... }

RandomTree<TrainingDataPoint, function_ptr, ProloadedImageCache>
```